# How to change linux kernel process priority in programmatic way?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

I found some function 'renice' that changes the nice value of process.

But I want to know how to change **priority in kernel code**.

Is it okay that just changing the priority value in sched_entity of process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the niceness of the process programmatically, I would advise against setting these values in the kernel struct directly. Instead, you can utilize several POSIX functions such as `setpriority` or `pthread_setschedparam`.

The default scheduler policy on Linux is `SCHED_OTHER`, so you're, by default, achieving the same thing using these two functions, as `SCHED_OTHER` just uses niceness level to schedule.

If you have access to the `task_struct`, in order to achieve this directly, you just need to set `static_prio` in `task_struct`.