# How to update the nice priority of a process from within the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Every process is first created by a `fork` system call, which ends up calling `_do_fork()` in file `/kernel/fork.c` at line 2416. Inside `_do_fork()` the function `copy_process()` is called, which is defined in `/kernel/fork.c` at line 1841. This function then calls `sched_fork()` at line 2068 which according to the commentary inside the source code “performs a scheduler related setup of the newly created process and assigns it to a CPU”. The function `sched_fork()` is defined in file `/kernel/sched/core.c` at [line 2999](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.13/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3014).

I wish to overwrite the `nice` priority of regular processes that have an uneven process ID from within the Linux kernel itself (Linux kernel `v5.3.18` to be specific). I am not interested in doing it from userspace. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709518/how-to-change-linux-kernel-process-priority-in-programmatic-way) suggests this should be theoretically as simple as setting the `static_prio` of a `task_struct`. So I reasoned that setting both the dynamic and static priorities in `sched_fork` would be a good choice, where the dynamic priority is (first?) assigned to a value (please click the previous link to see the source code of `sched_fork`).

For example, I tried to replace the line `p->prio = current->normal_prio;` with the following code:

```
if(fair_policy(p->policy))
        p->prio = p->static_prio = p->normal_prio = 117;
```

After compiling and installing, when I call `getpriority()` from userspace, it does indeed return the nice priority `-3` (equivalent to 117), but behavior-wise it is still acting as if its priority is the default value `0` (i.e. its still assigned the same CPU runtime as the default priority).

**So the question is, why is it that modifying `p->static_prio` and `p->prio` doesn't have any influence on the CPU timeslice that `p` receives?**

Here follows my reasoning:

Since getpriority returns -3, we at least know that 1) the static priority is indeed modified to 117, and 2) the process does get enqueued to the CFS runqueue (since the process runs succesfully).

I suspect that the load weight was calculated some place earlier, based on the 'old' static priority. For example, I notice that later on in `sched_fork` there's a call to `init_entity_runnable_average(&p->se);`, that is defined as follows:

```
/* Give new sched_entity start runnable values to heavy its load in infant time */
void init_entity_runnable_average(struct sched_entity *se)
{
    struct sched_avg *sa = &se->avg;

    memset(sa, 0, sizeof(*sa));

    /*
     * Tasks are initialized with full load to be seen as heavy tasks until
     * they get a chance to stabilize to their real load level.
     * Group entities are initialized with zero load to reflect the fact that
     * nothing has been attached to the task group yet.
     */
    if (entity_is_task(se))
        sa->load_avg = scale_load_down(se->load.weight);

    /* when this task enqueue'ed, it will contribute to its cfs_rq's load_avg */
}
```

So I think the `se->load.weight` may be based on the `static_priority` prior to it being overwritten. But if that is the case, then where does `se->load.weight` first get initialized when it is forked? I can't seem to find it.

**Edit:**
I modified the question to incorporate the issues that @MarcoBonelli addressed.

Comment: If you change the code in `fork`, that means that you have changed ***all*** processes in the system to have priority 117. What do you expect? It's the same as having all of them with priority 0. Also, priority does not increase "speed", it *may* increase the CPU time dedicated to the process by the scheduler.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am only changing processes that have an uneven process ID to 117. I suppose I should've clarified that, sorry. And by increasing speed, I mean it should run quicker relative to other processes that have a priority of 120. Again, my bad for not writing that down properly.

Comment: It should not run quicker. It should run more time, that's different. Anyway, how did you test this? You should go over what you did to ensure that this is the case.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You're right. I execute the same program twice in parallel using a batch script, and let them calculate millions of instructions to compare the relative speed. When I use `setpriority` syscall and set the nice value to -3, I get the outcome I desire, which is that processes with an uneven process ID get twice as much execution time as processes that have an even process ID. Now I'm trying to get this to work from within kernelspace. `nice -3` gives a process roughly twice as much execution time as `nice 0`, but it gets messy to elaborate the math behind it.

Comment: Not sure how I would go about this, but I would suggest looking at what the `setpriority` syscall does and try to implement that at process creation time.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I have tried to incorporate/simulate what the `setpriority` syscall does into `sched_fork`, but it causes the kernel to crash. It's sort of difficult to simulate since the `set_user_nice` (which `setpriority` calls) deals locking/unlocking the rq as well as dequeueing and requeuing the process. This doesn't seem necessary to me in `sched_fork`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I found that `set_load_weight(p, false);` after setting the `static_prio` to 117 works succesfully at overwriting the nice value. But for some reason now, it sometimes assigns a priority of -3 to processes with an even ID instead of an uneven ID (the latter situation is the goal), while in other times it works as intended. It's weird, cause it's just a simple if-else check based on whether the process id is even or not (`if(p->pid %  2 == 0)`).